# Protein and Spirulina

Tags: diet, exercise

I am working out, and I would like to make sure that I am taking in enough protein. I am a 21 year old male, and I do about an hour to an hour and a half of daily cardio type exercise. I currently weigh 85 kg (187 lbs) at 5'6".

I want to know how much protein should I be taking per day, and is there any problem or advantage in taking spirulina as tablets rather than in powder form?

Comment: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/29195/3736

Comment: The question does not say what is the supposed goal of exercise and taking proteins, so I'm not sure if any recommendation in the sense of "amount" of proteins would be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Recommendations for daily protein intake [vary widely](http://www.health.harvard.edu/blog/how-much-protein-do-you-need-every-day-201506188096). Expressed as a proportion of the person's body mass, a general requirement is considered to be 0.8 g per day and kg of body mass, that would be 68 g for you. If you are physically active, this might be more. [One study on strength athletes](http://jap.physiology.org/content/73/5/1986) concluded on protein requirements of 1.76 g.kg-1.day-1 for strength athletes, against 0.89 g.kg-1.day-1 for sedentary subjects. On the other hand (according to [this study](https://www.uscupstate.edu/uploadedFiles/Student_Affairs/Health_Promotion_and_Education/Protein%20II.pdf) for instance) endurance sport does not raise protein requirements significantly, so 1 g.kg-1.day-1 would be enough for endurance athletes. Also, since endurance sport raises general energy requirements, the protein requirements are actually easier to meet (in terms of percentage of proteins in energy intake).